# Memory error in Networkx while drawing a graph

Tags: python, networkx

I have a graph having 
**957267** Number of nodes ;
**1860761** Number of edges and 
Average degree is  3.8877

```
G=nx.from_edgelist(edge)            
print(nx.info(G))
nx.draw_spring(G)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

till print function, every thing work, but after that when I draw graph, I got the error

All the values in edge list are integers.
I am getting memory error. Though I have 8 GB ram, and SSD hard disk Is there a way to deal with it or alternative of NetworkX

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    nx.draw_spring(G)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 965, in draw_spring
    draw(G, spring_layout(G), **kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\layout.py", line 333, in fruchterman_reingold_layout
    pos = _fruchterman_reingold(A, k, pos_arr, fixed, iterations, dim)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\layout.py", line 388, in _fruchterman_reingold
    distance = np.linalg.norm(delta, axis=-1)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 2198, in norm
    return sqrt(add.reduce(s, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims))

MemoryError

Comment: That doesn't look like the full error message.  Could you share the portion of your code that is raising the error?  What is it that you're trying to do with the graph?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh please check now, I have modified ir